# How to change sum based on multiple select boxes with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a group of select boxes with different number values that are added together to produce a sum.

Instead of having to refresh the page every time I want the new value, how can the Jquery be altered so that the new selected values are remembered in the form, and the new sum is computed when the values are changed?

You can see what I'm trying to do here: http://jsfiddle.net/beehive/Za42G/3/

```
var combined = 0;
$("select").each(function() {
    combined += parseInt($(this).val());
});

$("#sum").html(combined);

$("#sum").change();
```

​

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible way:

```
$("select").change(function() {
    var combined = 0;
    $("select").each(function() {
        combined += parseInt(this.value, 10);
    });
    $("#sum").html(combined);
}).trigger("change");​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/Za42G/4/